# Parametrization of line bundles over an elliptic curve by points of that curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $E$ of degree $3$. Suppose, I can present this line bundle as 
$$
\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{O} (3p),
$$
for some point $p \in E$. Is it true that point $p$ is unique? If not, how one can describe all points $p \in E$ with fixed class of the divisor $[3p]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p$ is not unique, but any two possibilities for $p$ differ exactly by a 3-torsion point on $E$ (so there are exactly 9 possible values for $p$ that give the same divisor class). The basics of this are explained in chapter 3 of Silverman's AEC book, for example.

---

The main tool here is Corollary III.3.5 in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. It says that a divisor $D = \sum n_p \cdot (p)$ is principal if and only if it has degree zero and the sum (viewed as a sum using the group law on $E$) is equal to $O$, the marked point at infinity on $E$.

Clearly $3(p)\sim 3(p')$ if and only $3(p) - 3(p')$ is principal. Using the corollary mentioned above, this happens if and only if $3p \ominus 3p' = O$. But by commutativity of the group law, $3p \ominus 3p' = 3(p \ominus p')$, hence this happens if and only if $p$ and $p'$ differ by an element of $E[3]$.

Comment: I'm afraid I need more details, I don't see how to prove this.

Comment: @Alex: There are more details now.